# What are well known smoked cheese alternatives?

Tags: veganism, dairy-substitutes

What alternatives are well known or can be purchased in local supermarkets which taste most similar to smoked cheese?

**Note**:

- I'm living in the UK and shop weekly so I'm looking for alternatives I can consistently buy locally. (Preferably large supermarkets if possible)

Comment: I'm going to have to go on a quest to find this smoked vegan cheese... you've set off a craving

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find any products in local supermarkets except [this one](https://m.tesco.com/h5/groceries/r/www.tesco.com/groceries/product/details/default.aspx?id=277073874) at Tesco, but it's currently unavailable on their website. Otherwise though, I've found a [great cashew based recipe](http://www.nestandglow.com/healthy-recipes/smoked-cashew-vegan-cheese) for a three day supply (up to 12 servings) which takes around 15 minutes to make and it is as follows:

> **Ingredients**
>
> - 1 cup / 150g  Cashews
> - ½ cup / 40g  Nutritional yeast
> - 1 tbsp Smoked paprika
> - 1 tbsp Maple syrup
> - 1 tbsp Agar agar powder
> - 1 clove of Garlic
> - 1 Lemon juiced
> - ¼ tsp Turmeric
> - ¼ tsp Cayenne pepper
> - 1½ cups / 350ml Water
> - a pinch of Salt
>
> **Method**
>
> 1. Place half the water and everything else apart from the agar agar
>      into a blender.
> 2. Blend until smooth.
> 3. In a pan put in the remaining half of the water and the agar agar.
> 4. Simmer for 5 mins stirring constantly. Make sure no lumps of agar agar form at the bottom.
> 5. Take off the heat and stir in the cashew mixture until combined.
> 6. Pour into a mould and then chill for 2 hours.

<sup>Ingredients can be all sourced from one supermarket</sup>

Comment: Note that you can purchase 'liquid smoke' and add sparingly to create more smoke aroma than just by smoked paprika.

Comment: @henning I'll give both a try and see which I prefer, thanks for the tip

Comment: +1 I'd much rather make this than buy processed faux cheese anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

If you can find [Miyokos smoked English farmhouse](https://shop.miyokoskitchen.com/products/aged-english-smoked-farmhouse-vegan-cheese?variant=1068410931), it's pretty awesome.  Not sure how common it is in the UK though.

Comment: Alas, seems they don't do international orders. I wonder if Whole Foods in London stock it... I will investigate

Comment: It's ironic that something labeled 'English farmhouse' appears to not be stocked in England.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to vegan smoked cheeses, you might also want to consider smoked tofu. Clearspot, Cauldron and Taifun all have a smoked tofu that they sell in the UK, in health stores and some supermarkets. The taste and texture is not as close as a pukka vegan cheese, but if you are happy with a smoky/savoury taste and a vaguely cheese-like texture then this might satisfy your requirements.

Comment: This is a little off the mark imho, since smoked tofu, to me anyway, really doesn't taste like smoked cheese... although taifun make something they call "feto", a fermented tofu that tastes somewhat like feta, and if they made a smoked version of that it might come close

Comment: @Zanna: well, yes, it depends what you're looking for - personally I'm happy with a smoky taste and a vaguely cheese-like texture, but YMMV. I'll update the answer anyway to clarify.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for editing. Some visitors may indeed prefer this option and find your answer helpful. Personally I'm not very keen on processed vegan cheese but I love smoked tofu :)

Answer (score 0):

Tesco has [this product](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/295348477) which is quite good. :)

[image: Smoked Cheese - Coconut Oil Alternative]